# Restrict anyone from triggering CI on non-protected branches

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have my main branch protected. And I have configured my gitlab-ci to only execute on `main`.

My requirement is that, no one should be able to trigger CI, unless there changes are reviewed and merged to main. This works fine until, some developer-a updates the CI and removes `only: main` condition and then as soon as he pushes it to a branch, it triggers that particular step or steps. Even though the CI on main still has those conditions enforced and these changes arent yet merged.

Which version of `.gitlab-ci.yml` file gitlab uses to trigger to CI? From the above scenario I assume it’s the one the pushed branch and not the one on the `main`?

If above is true, is there a way to restrict this behavior and achieve what I want that is only trigger CI with the version of `main`, so no one can change it without due approval?

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

build-code-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Hello."
#  only:
#    - main

test-code-job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Test"
  only:
    - main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to [specify a custom configuration file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#specify-a-custom-cicd-configuration-file) in the project settings. For example, you can use a configuration value like `.gitlab-ci.yml@namespace/my-config-project:main` so that the CI configuration is always taken from a particular project on a particular branch. It can even be a different project with different developer permissions if you want.

Only users with maintainer permission or higher can change this project setting.